# Calling itunes web api to fetch the data

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I am very much new to the web API concept. I want to populate a div in my web page with the logo images of all the games of particular developer in itunes using the itunes web API. Can anyone please help me out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried? What isn't working?

Comment: @MatthewGroves I have tried a javascript framework called p5.js for parsing the data but I am not getting an idea on how to pass the value from the parsed data as an image source.
    var itunesData;

    function setup() {
      createCanvas(200,200);
      loadJSON('https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=jim+jones&country=ca', gotData);
    }

    function gotData(data) {
  
      //print(data);
      itunesData = data;
  
    }


    function draw(){
      background(255, 255, 0);
      if(itunesData){
        alert(itunesData.results[0].artworkUrl60);
      }
    }